# What is $\partial (A)$ and $\overline{A}$ of the following space?

Tags: general-topology

Consider in $\mathbb R$ the topology $\mathscr{T}$ generated by the basis $\mathscr{B}=\{[a, b): a, b\in\mathbb R, a<b\}$. What would be the closure and the boundary of the set $A=(0, 1]\times [0, 1)\subset \mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ where $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ is endowed with the product topology determined by $\mathscr{T}$.

I know $\overline{(0, 1]\times [0, 1)}=\overline{(0, 1]}\times \overline{[0, 1)}$ and I think $[0,1)$ is closed so that $\overline{[0, 1)}=[0, 1)$. As to $\overline{(0, 1]}$ I'm not sure but I guess it is $[0, 1]$.

I have already proven $\textrm{int}((0, 1]\times [0, 1))=(0, 1)\times [0, 1)$ so it is easy to find $\partial(A)$ if I know $\overline{A}$.

Any help will be valuable!

Thanks!

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem so far? What have you tried? What definition(s) have you encountered for closure? boundary set? Product topology? The more you can tell us, the better we can tailor our answers to your needs.

Comment: @CameronBuie I added some thoughts in the post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thoughts so far are spot on! To see why $\overline{(0,1]}=[0,1],$ note/prove first that $[0,1]$ is closed under the topology $\mathscr{T}.$ Thus, $\overline{(0,1]}\subseteq[0,1].$ Now, if $U$ is a $\mathscr{T}$-open set containing $0,$ can you show that $U$ must intersect $(0,1]$? That will prove that $0$ is an element of $\overline{(0,1]},$ and so the reverse inclusion follows.

Comment: I'll try to write it =), thanks!

Comment: If you want to double-check your reasoning with me afterward, feel free! I'm glad to help.

Comment: Ok, thanks again!